# Is it possible to prevent user from uninstalling application in Android?

Tags: android, security

I want to prevent user from uninstalling my application.But my main objective is to ask the password before uninstallation of the applcation.Is it Possible in android.

Comment: Now why would you want to do that? It would upset me if I couldn't uninstall your application.

Comment: my main objective is to ask the password before uninstalling my application.Is it Possible?

Comment: So what happens in the event that the user forgets the password? Are they forever stuck with your application installed until they factory reset? Like kabuko, I'm completely against this in general unless you are distributing your application as part of the core device.

Comment: I totally agree with you @Deco but my client is demanding it that's why i am asking is it possible?

Comment: @Deco: but at least to give a dialog box "Are you sure to uninstall?" is not a bad habit or malware ?

Comment: Like @kabuko said, the normal way of uninstalling already gives you a confirmation, there's no point in adding in another one; so it would be bad practice. The client has a requirement which cannot reasonably be achieved, therefore the requirement should be scoped out or changed to something that can be achieved. I order to achieve this the app would need root access to the device, or be distributed as part of the device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot prevent user from uninstalling your app.

Comment: can i ask the password before uninstallation of the application?

Comment: no. The uninstallation is done from the settings app,and ur app is not in control of it.

Comment: Can i create a watcher which monitors it and when user try to uninstall it asks the password?

Comment: Even if you succeed in doing so, you cannot stop the uninstall. Its of no use asking password when you cannot stop uninstallation.

Comment: You can handle uninstall broadcasts, but that broadcast is for "this application has uninstalled". This means that the application that was uninstalled has already been uninstalled and is not eligible to receive that broadcast. You can only do this from a separate application and again, this is after the fact, not right before the uninstall.

Comment: @kabuko:but at least to give a dialog box "Are you sure to uninstall?" is not a bad habit or malware ?

Comment: @userSeven7s:but at least to give a dialog box "Are you sure to uninstall?" is not a bad habit or malware ?

Comment: @Sameer The normal way of uninstalling an application through Manage Applications already gives you an uninstall confirmation dialog. There is no need to add another one.

Comment: Wrong Yes we can prevent , there is a App named SMS Lock which prevents app to uninstall , when opening uninstall tab it ask to enter password

Comment: If i develop native app then, Is it possible to prevent user from uninstalling application in Android?

Comment: @Pradeep No. Your app at no point in time will have control over the Settings app(unless somehow hacked on rooted devices.)Settings app will broadcast the uninstall only after completely uninstalling your app. If you have another app monitoring your app then it may receive the broadcast, but it too cannot stop uninstallation.
The apps that are built with the OS are the only ones that cannot be uninstalled by user, but can be disabled.

Answer (score 8):

Not without doing something fairly in depth. First of all, I'm completely against this in general. If it's their device, they should be able to remove your app from their device. That said, there are some corner cases where this might be valid. Manufacturers seem to do this a lot (actually, in my opinion this is one of those cases which is *not* valid but that's a whole other story). They install apps into the system partition, which the user doesn't have rights to modify. You could do the same if you're actually distributing the device. If you want to just do this for a regular Market app, then no.

Comment: Can i create a watcher which monitors it and when user try to uninstall it asks the password?

Comment: No. Like we're all saying, this is not a good thing and so Android doesn't support it. It would lead to malware. Don't do it, don't try it, tell your client that's not a good requirement. I know it sounds harsh, but sometimes you need to not always do what your client tells you, but instead educate them on why something they want is not a good idea (and in this case, not possible).

Comment: What if you are creating an Enterprise app(non-Market) with a phone that you are configuring and giving to the consumer.  Then I can see this as a good thing.