# uninstall Application Password Protected

Tags: android

How to start an Activity or an IntentService before an application will be uninstalled by the user who has earlier installed the app on there device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to prevent user from uninstalling application in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178982/is-it-possible-to-prevent-user-from-uninstalling-application-in-android)

Comment: Have u got the Answer Of that Questions?

Comment: Yes i got the answer..what you want is not possible

Comment: ohk thanks ,But the NQ Security Application Provide that Facility .so it may be Possible .
what do u think about that ????

Comment: Finally i have done that Task :) nothing is Impossible .

Comment: i am surprised..I will be good to share your solution with other so that rest will not need to struggle

Comment: by using Device Administration i make it possible uninstall application password protected .check this --

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#developing

Comment: @Sameer sir,sure if u need the code then i will share that code here .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819780/password-protected-uninstall-in-android-4-versions-programmatically
try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prefend an user removing an application.

The DELETE intent will be send when the user requests to uninstall.
The PackageManager will receive this intent and start uninstalling the application.

So, without any Android modifications, you cannot add an password.

Comment: i have search a lot about that issue but not get anything .i think this is impossible task .

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you want would include the following steps:

1. (temporarily) rooting the device
2. converting the app in question into a system app (e.g. using Titanium Backup ★ root, but there are also other apps helping you with this step)
3. unroot the device again
   As the app now resides in read-only space (/system), the user cannot delete it without either rooting the device or flashing a ROM -- which of course could be done, but it's a higher inhibition threshold at least.

There is no such thing as impossible with computers. There is only difficult and highly improbable to happen anytime soon. This is a fact not an opinion. Often someone says "impossible" and there is someone interrupting them saying "Just did it.".

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Intent filter called "android.intent.action.DELETE" in the AndroidManifest.xml
Like below

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="package"  />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This will call the activity.

Comment: i have earlier try that code but this is Not Showing an Activity Before Uninstall the Package .