# password protected uninstall in android 4+ versions [programmatically]

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, uninstallation, password-protection

i want my app to have a password protected uninstall ... (like app lock)

im using folling code it works on **Android 2.3** but not on **Android 4+** versions

**MANIFEST FILE**

```
  <receiver android:name="fyp.invisibleink.UninstallIntentReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="0" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART" />

            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

---

**Uninstalling Activity code**

```
ublic class Uninstalling extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_uninstalling);

    // listener
    Button settingsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnu);
    settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpass);

            final String pass = e1.getText().toString();

            SharedPreferences cupSetting = getSharedPreferences(
                    "cuppassword", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String mypass = cupSetting.getString("pass", "");

            if (pass.equals(mypass)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "password is correct!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "press OK to uninstall!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Access Denied! try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                e1.setText("");

            }
        }
    });

}
```

---

**UninstallReceveier**

```
public class UninstallIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // fetching package names from extras
    String[] packageNames = intent
            .getStringArrayExtra("android.intent.extra.PACKAGES");

    if (packageNames != null) {
        for (String packageName : packageNames) {
            if (packageName != null
                    && packageName.equals("com.example.invisibleink")) {
                // User has selected our application under the Manage Apps
                // settings
                // now initiating background thread to watch for activity
                new ListenActivities(context).start();

            }
        }
    }
}

// ///////////////////////////////
class ListenActivities extends Thread {
    boolean exit = false;
    ActivityManager am = null;
    Context context = null;

    public ListenActivities(Context con) {
        context = con;
        am = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Looper.prepare();

        while (!exit) {

            // get the info from the currently running task
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am
                    .getRunningTasks(MAX_PRIORITY);

            String activityName = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity
                    .getClassName();

            Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::" + activityName);

            if (activityName
                    .equals("com.android.packageinstaller.UninstallerActivity")) {
                // User has clicked on the Uninstall button under the Manage
                // Apps settings

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Uninstalling.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                exit = true;
                // do whatever pre-uninstallation task you want to perform
                // here
                // show dialogue or start another activity or database
                // operations etc..etc..

                // context.startActivity(new Intent(context,
                // MyPreUninstallationMsgActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

            } else if (activityName
                    .equals("com.android.settings.ManageApplications")) {
                // back button was pressed and the user has been taken back
                // to Manage Applications window
                // we should close the activity monitoring now
                exit = true;
            }
        }
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

}

---

**Permissioms**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive, so please correct me if I'm wrong but this might have been removed as a security feature. A malicious app might be able to create a password and avoid the app from being removed creating further damage on the device. Like I said, I could be wrong but this is a guess that seems legit. I noticed that 4+ did a couple things for security because of a lot of malicious stuff and exploits happening within 3rd party apps.

Comment: u might b right be applications like "APP LOCK" exist in market how do you think they are working?

Comment: They might be using root. Are they? Because using root privileges gives you access to libraries such as Xposed and CydiaSubstrate (for Android) allowing you to override system classes. If they ARE using root privileges then you might be able to do the same using this: https://github.com/SpazeDog/rootfw and this: http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/

Comment: this might be helpful .. let me work on it ...thanks buddy for your support .