# complete password protected android app

Tags: java, android, android-service

I  created a security app in which your can login with username and password. It's working fine except one thing, User can uninstall this app from google settings or they clear data, Then my app has no security, Ya then can login but all the features which is enabled after login are closed. so i want to use my login password when i am uninstalling my app or doing clear cache.

How i can do this? I searched on internet and not found anything useful.
Similar type question is here, but not answered.
[password protected uninstall in android 4+ versions [programmatically]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819780/password-protected-uninstall-in-android-4-versions-programmatically)

My app is only for android 4.+ devices.

Comment: This is unclear, how can someone use an uninstalled application?

Comment: Short answer: You can't. You could however use your own server for authentication, ie. Have users sign in to your app.

Comment: Ya user is sign-in, I can use server for authentication, But how i ask for password when uninstalling app?

Comment: You can't. If you don't use a custom ROM, there are things you can't prevent.

Comment: Then how some apps are doing this in 4.0+ OS? Like appLock and other locking applications??

Comment: They are exploiting security flaws in the device that I have been working diligently with Google to get closed.