# prevent uninstall of applications in android

Tags: android

we are developing an app that tracks the device in case it is stolen, the application should be in the device even after being stolen so that the we get periodic messages from the device. Is there a way to stop the person, who stole the mobile, from uninstalling the app? and also how to prevent force stop option of the app through the manage application > myApp > force stop.

Comment: Look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/q/8178982/614807

Comment: You can try using making your application DeviceAdmin. But user can uninstall after deactivating device admin, of course

Comment: This question is already being answered on this page, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540002/how-to-prevent-an-application-from-being-uninstalled?newreg=16abec00005c406b8d922d3565bf24bb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent an application from being uninstalled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540002/how-to-prevent-an-application-from-being-uninstalled)

Answer (score 1):

No,you cannot change Android framework specification which are available currently.

Uninstall and rebooting is truly and forcefully handled by android OS.