# How to install an application on android device that no one can remove it from settings

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to prevent user from uninstalling application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178982/is-it-possible-to-prevent-user-from-uninstalling-application-in-android)

Thanks in advance for paying attention on this problem...!!

Is this possible to install an `application` that no one can `uninstall` it. I just mean that by going

```
setting --> Apps --> Manage Applications --> by selecting an app and click on UnInstall.
```

I want that If I install an `application` in a device, then no one can `uninstall` it.

Comment: Why do you want that? It seems like malignant behavior.

Comment: Hey Nikita..., Its nt possible to discuss that why I want to do that dear. I m also searching on that & if I got anything helpful then I'll try to share.

Comment: Simon... I also agree with that..., but here a slightly different mechanism.., IN ur case: User is not able to displaying his/her own layout during uninstalling process coz when I uninstall an app then I m tottaly on Device view.., At that time I am nt opening my app its nt possible to asking for the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You just have to write/modify your own custom rom. If you're in a large corporation/organization. Your corporation/organization may want to have its own rom for its own employees' company-owned phones.

Or if you're in the consumer space, the other option is to convince a cell phone carrier to make your app a default one (and to prevent the user from uninstalling it). This is not a technical challenge. It's just a commercial one. Be prepared to pay them lots of money to have you installed by default on their phones.

And be prepared for some serious backlash in your ratings in the Google Play/Market. Two years ago, I was incredibly frustrated at having the NASCAR application on my phone, that I couldn't uninstall (despite the fact that I couldn't care less about NASCAR), and of course, I wasn't the only one. The app's rating went down to 1 star because of this and created lots of ill-will towards NASCAR.

Comment: My smartphone, a quite old one, has only 150 MB of system memory and half the space is occupied by manufacturer preinstalled and unremovable applications I couldn't care less. +1 for hate against such a policy.

Comment: Hey Stephan, If i have an application in android which sends the sim number to the server as the sim card will change and I also want to control the mobile device functionality like camera, contacts etc. from server side, just the process is that you need to install the application on the device and after that I need to disable mobile functionality from server. Its just because of security issue. So I need that no one uninstall these kind of apps.